# RX and CancelEventArg

Tags: events, system.reactive

Is there an equivalent of CancelEventArg for RX?  I have updating events in my repository that fire before the save.  I retrieve the InvocationList and iterate over each EventHandler to check if the cancel flag is set to abort the save.   I’m a RX newbie and from watching the RX workshop on Observable vs Events http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Rx-Workshop/Rx-Workshop-Observables-versus-Events  I was wondering how I could replace the EventHandler with a Subject and know if one of the subscribers cancels the event.

If I can’t convert the event to a Subject is there a way to get an Observable for the EventHandler and in the OnNext get access to the sender and CancelEventArgs from the EventHandler invocation?

Comment: Even though you can write a subject which allows stopping notifications to its subscribers, this is not recommended. Look for an alternative way to model the problem without mutability.

Answer (score 0):

With Observable.FromEvent you have access to the event args, like e.g. here:

```
IObservable<Key> keyPress = 
    Observable.FromEvent<KeyEventArgs>(Application.Current.RootVisual, "KeyUp")
        .Select(ev => ev.EventArgs.Key);
```

So you should be able to set the value of any property in the event args.

Note that you have a design issue here: Cancellation is something you should already be careful with in a normal context, but mixing cancellable events and asynchroneous execution paths might turn into a maintenance nightmare later. Use a producer-consumer-pattern here and think of it as a one-way communication: you react on an event, you should not change it. If you need to change it, use a filter (via Rx utility methods).